# How do I set the text opacity different from the background opacity in a Silverlight textbox

Tags: silverlight, xaml, textbox, opacity

My **XAML** contains in part

```
<TextBox Text="PROJECTED"
         TextAlignment="Center"
         FontSize="11"
         FontWeight="Bold"
         Foreground="White"
         Background="#FF3376B8"
         Opacity="0.65" />
```

However, this causes the text to also be 65% opaque;

How do I set the text to be 100% opaque but allow the background to be 65%?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it by adjusting the Alpha channel of the Background property.

For example:

```
<TextBox Text="PROJECTED"
         TextAlignment="Center"
         FontSize="11"
         FontWeight="Bold"
         Foreground="White"
         Background="#883376B8" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the VS/Expression Blend property editor UI to adjust the opacity of any color property by adjusting the A value in your color's RGBA value (0....255, lower is more opaque)

This will obviously change the hex value of your color but will give you the view you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<TextBox Text="PROJECTED"
         TextAlignment="Center"
         FontSize="11"
         FontWeight="Bold"
         Foreground="White"">
    <TextBox.Background>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF3376B8"
                         Opacity="0.65" />
    </TextBox.Background>
</TextBox >
```

Comment: This changed nothing for me : the background is still totally opaque when the TextBox is focused, and transparent when it looses focus (I used Transparent color).

Comment: This should have worked. Opacity of the TextBox  affects everything about it (and children). Opacity of the brush only affects it and not the text.